# How to stream WiFi cameras over a Linux gateway to my laptop using iptables?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, routing, iptables

My setup is as follows:

- Linux gateway has one WLAN configured as WiFi client (192.168.0.100) to a Linksys WiFi AP(192.168.0.1).
- There are three WiFi cameras connected as WiFi clients (192.168.0.101, .102 and .103) to the Linksys router.
- The Linux gateway also has a wired ethernet port `eth0` (100.0.100.100) connected point-2-point using CAT5 cable with the laptop (100.0.100.200).

How can I, using browsers, stream cameras from 192.168.0.101, .102 and .103 to my laptop? There is no display on the Linux box. I've looked at examples on the internet, but haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: Can the cameras stream via http ?

Comment: @ Lawrence.Yes.I have tested by making my laptop another wifi client to linksys wifi AP.